# python extension link dylib on osx

Tags: python, c++

I make a python extension `bar_extension` with `distutils`.`bar_extension` need a shared object `libfoo.dylib` which is made by `cmake`.
Here is my `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('bar_extension',
                libraries=['libfoo2.dylib', ],
                library_dirs=['/Users/xiazhibin/CLionProjects/study/lib', ],
                include_dirs=['/Users/xiazhibin/CLionProjects/study/include', ],
                language="c++",
                extra_compile_args = ['-v', '--std=c++98', ],
                sources=['main.cpp'])

setup(name='PackageName',
  version='1.0',
  description='This is a demo package',
  ext_modules=[module1])
```

output is here:

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo" -create -output build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/main.o /var/folders/45/gz7ljrz94mdct3nvm9l5ftnr0000gp/T/main-5498b8.o /var/folders/45/gz7ljrz94mdct3nvm9l5ftnr0000gp/T/main-0bc98d.o
c++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/main.o -L/Users/xiazhibin/CLionProjects/study/lib -llibfoo2.dylib -o build/lib.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/bar.so
ld: library not found for -llibfoo2.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
```

My `libfoo2.dylib` is under path `/Users/xiazhibin/CLionProjects/study/lib`,but it seems that can not find my `libfoo2.dylib`

How was that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a _C++_ compiler installed? Typically _c++_ is a symlink to the compiler executable. Long shot (assuming you have _gcc_ installed): `alias c++=g++` before building the extension.

Comment: @CristiFati yes, I do.I make the `libfoo2. dylib ` with `cmake`.I install the gcc also

Comment: Try using 'foo2' instead of 'libfoo2.dylib'